# Run a bash script from docky

Tags: ubuntu, bash, docky

Using docky under ubuntu, I want to be able to run bash scripts.

When I drag and drop a script from nautilus to docky, the script appears on docky.  But clicking on the script icon opens the script in gedit.

Was wondering if anyone knows how to configure docky to run the script.

Comment: Whomever marked a negative against my question, it would probably be more constructive if you actually left a comment as to why...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try creating a .desktop file to run the script and drag that onto Docky. The easiest way might be to:

(1) Drag one of your menu items off the main menu and onto your desktop. This will create a .desktop file on the desktop.

(2) Right click the icon and choose Properties.

(3) Change the line that begins with Command to say "bash /path/to/your/script".

(4) Select Close.

(5) Drag that icon to Docky.

If right-clicking on the icon doesn't come up with a Properties editor, just edit in gEdit or Emacs or your favorite text editor.

Comment: Thanks, awesome advice.
I was trying to run intellij IDE.

I created a file containing the following, and dragged to docky. Worked!

[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Intellij
Exec=/home/ben/bin/idea-IU-117.418/bin/idea.sh
Icon=/home/ben/bin/idea-IU-117.418/bin/idea.png

Answer (score 0):

This works on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Took an existing 'dot' keyboard file I had and edited:

```
Exec=/home/my_user/my_script_directory/script_name.sh
Terminal=true
```

Dragged it to Docky and then the script is run in a terminal window. If you don't want to see the terminal window set `Terminal=false`.